# Forcing pandas .iloc to return a single-row dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

For programming purpose, I want `.iloc` to consistently return a data frame, even when the resulting data frame has only one row. How to accomplish this?

Currently, `.iloc` returns a Series when the result only has one row. Example:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2], 'b':[3,4]})

In [2]: df
Out[2]:
   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4

In [3]: type(df.iloc[0, :])
Out[3]: pandas.core.series.Series
```

This behavior is poor for 2 reasons:

- Depending on the number of chosen rows, `.iloc` can either return a Series or a Data Frame, forcing me to manually check for this in my code

<strike>- `.loc`, on the other hand, always return a Data Frame, making `pandas` inconsistent within itself</strike> (wrong info, as pointed out in the comment)

For the R user, this can be accomplished with `drop = FALSE`, or by using tidyverse's tibble, which always return a data frame by default.

Comment: `.loc` *does not* always return a `pd.DataFrame`, indeed, try `df.loc[0,:]` and you'll get the same behavior.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga You're correct -- I'll edit that wrong info out of my post.

Answer (score 221):

Use double brackets,

```
df.iloc[[0]]
```

Output:

```
   a  b
0  1  3

print(type(df.iloc[[0]])

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Short for `df.iloc[[0],:]`

Comment: Note it also works on `df.loc[[0], :]` ! I came here for hope and found gold. Thanks

Comment: Lol, I have been using pandas for quite a long time now, I came to realize this now. I just used to call `to_frame` then transpose the frame.

Answer (score 27):

### Accessing row(s) by label: `loc`

```
# Setup
df = pd.DataFrame({'X': [1, 2, 3], 'Y':[4, 5, 6]}, index=['a', 'b', 'c'])
df        

   X  Y
a  1  4
b  2  5
c  3  6
```

To get a DataFrame instead of a Series, pass a list of indices of length 1,

```
df.loc[['a']]
# Same as
df.loc[['a'], :] # selects all columns

   X  Y
a  1  4
```

To select multiple specific rows, use

```
df.loc[['a', 'c']] 

   X  Y
a  1  4
c  3  6
```

To select a contiguous range of rows, use

```
df.loc['b':'c'] 

   X  Y
b  2  5
c  3  6
```

### Access row(s) by position: `iloc`

Specify a list of indices of length 1,

```
i = 1
df.iloc[[i]]

   X  Y
b  2  5
```

Or, specify a slice of length 1:

```
df.iloc[i:i+1] 

   X  Y
b  2  5
```

To select multiple rows or a contiguous slice you'd use a similar syntax as with `loc`.

Answer (score 5):

The double-bracket approach doesn't always work for me (e.g. when I use a conditional to select a timestamped row with loc).

You can, however, just add `to_frame()` to your operation.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2], 'b':[3,4]})

>>> df2 = df.iloc[0, :].to_frame().transpose()

>>> type(df2)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Comment: From a suggested edit: "Note: this swaps the index and columns: for the example above, `df` is 2 x 2 while the selected *row* `df2` is 2 x 1. The row number (`0`) became the column name, while the column names (`'a'` and `'b'`) became the new index."

Comment: Thank you, good catch, ppery.  I added a transpose() method to get the desired result.

Comment: This is a bad solution: if the columns of the `DataFrame` are of different data types, then when squeezing to `Series`, pandas will upcast to `object`. You are not guaranteed to get the same data types for the columns back as in the original DataFrame! One can do a little bit better by casting back to the original data types, but I think even then you are not guaranteed to not have some loss of information in some edge cases due to the automatic casting rules.

Answer (score 2):

please use the below options:

```
df1 = df.iloc[[0],:]
#type(df1)
df1
```

or

```
df1 = df.iloc[0:1,:]
#type(df1)
df1
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting single row extraction from Dataframe use:

```
df_name.iloc[index,:].to_frame().transpose()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
single_Sample1=df.iloc[7:10]
single_Sample1
```

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHHDZ.png**strong text**